# C++\CLI DateTime calculation error

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to predict the estimated completion time of a simulation. I take `startTime` at the start of the simulation. At the end of each cycle, I take `timeNow`. The time elapsed `timeLapsed` is calculated by subtracting these two values. The average cycle time (varies per cycle) is calculated by dividing the elapsed time by the cycle number at that time, i.e. number of cycles run until then. Then I calculate the estimated completion time `estimEndTime` by adding the number of cycles still to go multiplied by the average cycle time to `timeNow`.

I think something goes wrong in the data conversion, as the `estimEndTime` calculation is incorrect. Its prediction is way, way too short / soon. The average cycle time `avgCycleTime` is calculated at around 30-50 seconds which looks correct. Trial nr of cycles is 20.

I get one warning for the conversion of the cycle number (int i) from int64 to long with possible loss of data, but since the `avgCycleTime` seems ok, this does not seem to be the cause for the error.

Why doesn't this work?

Code essentials:

```
long avgCycleTime;

DateTime startTime = DateTime::Now;

f1->textBox9->Text = startTime.ToString("dd/MM/yy  HH:mm:ss");
f1->textBox9->Update();

i = 0;  // cycle counter
while (i < nCycl)
{

    // this is where the simulation occurs

    i++;

    DateTime timeNow = DateTime::Now;
    TimeSpan timeLapsed = timeNow.Subtract(startTime);
    avgCycleTime = (timeLapsed.Ticks / i);
    DateTime estimEndTime = timeNow.AddTicks(avgCycleTime * (nCycl-i));

    f1->textBox10->Text = Convert::ToString(avgCycleTime / 10000000); // cycle time in milliseconds
    f1->textBox11->Text = estimEndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yy  HH:mm:ss");
    f1->Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you declared `avgCycleTime` as `long` - effectively `Int32`.
Let's assume that one cycle takes 50 seconds. In ticks it would be `50 * 10,000,000 = 500,000,000` - well fit in `Int32`. But then you calculate `avgCycleTime * (nCycl - i)` and it overflows (result will be `Int32`), thus you get invalid `estimEndTime`. So you have to declare `avgCycleTime` as `long long` or `Int64`.

Comment: Once again stackoverflow comes to the rescue! Thanks Ulugbek, it works fine now.